# How to get a text Node from a DOM node?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to crate a Range Object by using

```
let range = document.createRange();
```

As you all know we must call

```
range.setStart(startNode,startOffset) ;
```

and

```
range.setEnd(endNode,endOffset);
```

I want to pass text nodes for both startNode and endNode, because if you pass a DOM node, you cannot specify custom offsets. My question is how can i get the text node of an element.

I just dont want just text as String, i want the text node.

suppose i have a paragraph

```
<p id="para">This is a paragraph</p>
```

i can get the DOM node by calling

```
let para = document.getElementById('para');
```

But how can i get the text node which is inside paragraph?

I want it as a text node, not like just a string. Please help.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmcshehan/0ks745ne/)

Answer (score 3):

To get the TextNode from

```
 <p id="para">This is a paragraph</p>
```

you just need `para.childNodes[0]`.

```js
console.log(para.childNodes[0].nodeName, para.childNodes[0].textContent);
```

```html
<p id="para">This is a paragraph</p>
```

However beware, if you actually had

```
<p id="para"><!--some comment-->
This is a paragraph
</p>
```

then this would return the CommentNode:

```js
console.log(para.childNodes[0].nodeName, para.childNodes[0].textContent);
```

```html
<p id="para"><!--some comment-->
This is a paragraph
</p>
```

And even, depending on how your element has been populated, you may very well have different TextNodes in the same element:

```js
para.append('This ', 'is ', 'a ', 'paragraph');
console.log(para.childNodes[0].nodeName, para.childNodes[0].textContent);
```

```html
<p id="para"></p>
```

So you'd probably want to iterate over each Nodes of the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) NodeList, or simply call setStart on your Element since it's also allowed:

```js
const range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(para,0);
range.setEnd(para, para.childNodes.length);
// which is actually the same as range.selectNode(para)

getSelection().addRange(range);
```

```html
<p id="para">This is a paragraph</p>
```

---

And if you really need to walk along the TextNodes of your element, then consider using a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) with the `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT` filter:

```js
para.append('This ', 'is ', 'a ', 'paragraph');
function getNodeAtTextIndex(elem, index) {
  const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    elem,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    null,
    false
  );
  let str = '';
  while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    const node = treeWalker.currentNode;
    str += node.textContent;
    if(str.length >= index) return {
      node: node,
      index: node.length - (str.length - index)
    };
  }
  return null;
}

const start = getNodeAtTextIndex(para, 2);
const end = getNodeAtTextIndex(para, 9);
const range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(start.node, start.index);
range.setEnd(end.node, end.index);
getSelection().addRange(range);
```

```html
<p id="para"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `para.innerText` to get the value `This is a paragraph` out.

Update: this should work for you.

`const textNode = document.querySelector('#para').childNodes[0];`

Comment: It returns String, not a node. It gives an error ---> 
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: Try using that String to create a node using `let textNode = document.createTextNode(para.innerText)`

Comment: I tried it, but when i create in that way. It says that the range is not in the document ----> addRange(): The given range isn't in document.

Comment: I updated the question with a jsfiddle, please check if you got time

Answer (score 0):

Every `DOMElement` has a `childNodes` array-like object that you can access.
Try changing the `textNode` value with

```
const textNode = document.querySelector('#para').childNodes[0];
```

Comment: @Kaiido answer covers some useful edge cases